# What does this sentence mean "Let me have your report by Friday"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand the phrase "**to have your report**" in "**Let me have your report by Friday**".

Does it mean "**to hold your report**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase

> Let me have *(it)*

can mean "hand *it* over to me" or "hit me with *it*" and is often use as a [joking pun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOp8aL37dQ8&t=0m18s).

The person is telling you to hand over your report by Friday.
On Friday, if they say "Let me have your report", you'd be advised not to throw it at them.